# Webflux @RequestBody return 400 BAD_REQUEST

Tags: spring-boot, http-post, spring-webflux

When developing a controller webflux on post request  in the parameters of the controller, I pass the request body using the annotation, but in webtestclient method return 400 BAD_REQUEST

**My DTO**:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class VisitRequest {

    private String description;

    public static Visit createEntityFromDto(Long customerId, Long deviceId, VisitRequest visitRequest) {
        return new Visit(null, customerId, deviceId, visitRequest.getDescription(),
                null);
    }
}
```

**My Controller**:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = VisitController.REST_URL)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class VisitController {
    static final String REST_URL = "/api/customers/{customerId}/devices/{deviceId}";

    private final VisitService visitService;

    //POST http://visits-service/api/customers/{customerId}/devices/{deviceId}/visits
    @PostMapping(value = "/visits", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<Visit> save(@PathVariable("customerId") @Validated long customerId,
                            @PathVariable("deviceId") @Validated long deviceId,
                            @RequestBody VisitRequest visitRequest) {
        log.info("save {} for customer_id: {}, device_id {}", visitRequest, customerId, deviceId);
        return visitService.save(createEntityFromDto(customerId, deviceId, visitRequest))
                .switchIfEmpty(error(new RuntimeException("Bad request for save visit:" + visitRequest)));
    }
}
```

**My Test class with WebTestClient**:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = VisitApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class VisitControllerTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Test
    void save() throws Exception {
        WebTestClient
                .bindToServer()
                .baseUrl("http://localhost:" + port)
                .build()
                .post()
                .uri("/api/customers/" + ONE.getCustomerId()
                     + "/devices/" + ONE.getDeviceId() + "/visits")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .bodyValue(new VisitRequest("test"))
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isCreated()
                .expectHeader().valueEquals("Content-Type", MediaTypes.ALPS_JSON_VALUE);
    }
}
```

When I run the test, WebTestClient return:

```
> POST http://localhost:63028/api/customers/10000/devices/20000/visits
> WebTestClient-Request-Id: [1]
> Content-Type: [application/json]
> Accept: [application/json]
> Content-Length: [22]

{"description":"test"}

< 400 BAD_REQUEST Bad Request
< Content-Type: [application/json]
< Content-Length: [169]

{"timestamp":"2020-09-27T19:28:09.987+00:00","path":"/api/customers/10000/devices/20000/visits","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","requestId":"42d54765-1"}
```

When I put a breakpoint on the logging line in the save method controller in the IntelliJ IDEA, and when I run the test in debug, the controller returns a bad request before reaching the breakpoint

Please help me find the cause of the error

Comment: Use @PostMapping(value = REST_URL) instead of @PostMapping(value = "/visits")